# “Would” or “would have”

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs

I have questions about the difference between "would" and "would have".

> "Would you do a tattoo?"
> "A few years ago I would have said 'no'. Now I would say 'maybe'."

Is the answer “A few years ago I *would have* said” correct or I should have only used *would*?

And the next one.
I'm talking about the past, let's say I’m thinking about the 90s.
And is it correct when I say: “If I had been a singer I would have been famous?”
I wanna say it about the past, about the 90s.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are using this construction correctly.

**would have** + past participle (e.g. said, been) refers to a past conditional or hypothetical.

If you had been asked to do a tattoo, you **would have said** no.

If you had been a singer in the 90's, you **would have been** famous.